# Disabled input still responds to mouse events after bind to disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, bind

I'm using Khavilo Dmitry's jQuery [checkbox code](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/) for checkboxes and radio buttons. This looks good, but his disable code doesn't work. The button is grayed out, as expected, but it still responds to mouse clicks.

I'm guessing that the problem is that he binds to disable as follows:

```
var ch = this; /* Reference to DOM Element*/
...   
$ch.bind('disable', function() {ch.wrapperInner.addClass(settings.cls+'-disabled');})
   .bind('enable',  function() {ch.wrapperInner.removeClass(settings.cls+'-disabled');});
```

Is this code removing any default binding that would disable mouse events? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it's not working. Clicking the disabled examples on his site do nothing, as expected. Browser issue maybe?

Comment: In my code, when the input is disabled, it grays out, but clicking on it still fires a mouse event (on multiple browsers). The code on KD's website isn't (I think) intended to do anything when a disabled button is clicked, so it doesn't test events. The disabled buttons are, for all intents and purposes, just images. Even the enabled buttons don't appear to have any events registered on them (I think, after a quick look on Firebug).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that code is doing is binding functions to the events 'disable' & 'enable'

When the 'disable' event is fired he is adding a class `jquery-checkbox-disabled` to the inner span. He removes it on the enable event.

```
<input name="checkbox.1.2" type="checkbox" id="check" checked="" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden; " disabled="disabled">
<span class="jquery-checkbox jquery-checkbox-checked">
  <span class="mark jquery-checkbox-disabled">
    <img src="empty.png">
  </span>
</span>
```

As you can see, The checkbox does get disabled, but the elements that provide you that custom look are just regular spans which are still clickable.

It appears that Dmitry is passing on the click events of these spans to the hidden checkbox.

```
a.wrapper.click(function(e) {
                b.trigger('click', [e]);
                i(e);
                return false
            });
```

This is why you're still getting the click events of the checkbox even though it is disabled. The checkbox is being programatically clicked.

So if your issue is that you're trying to detect when the checkbox has changed, then I recommend you use the change event as it does not seem to suffer from the same issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/vW6gj/

Comment: Thanks - very nice jsfiddle, but it unfortunately behaves differently on FF (only one box), Opera (disable ignored), and Chrome (seems to be Ok). However, I can't really use the change event. I need to make sure that the user doesn't click on a disabled box, because that still fires my own event, and everything goes wrong, because I assume that it's impossible to click on a disabled box. One option is for me to check whether the box is disabled when I get the event, but that just feels wrong. Any idea why Dmitry has to pass on the click event, or what the hidden box is for?

Comment: The hidden checkbox is your original checkbox. It's what you're binding your click events to and what your checking for state (checked or not checked). Because of this, he has to pass the click event to the hidden checkbox. This way your events fire and you can check the state of the box. You could modify his plugin and add a check in `a.wrapper.click(...` to make sure the checkbox is not disabled before triggering the click. Other than that, checking for disabled in your click events may be your only other option.